# Redirect root index.php to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've installed wordpress into a folder and I would like to redirect root index.php to wordpress the folder without using

> header('Location: ./folder/');

or meta redirect.
I would like to redirect only index file with something like **.htaccess** rules. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I've expressed myself badly, I need a sort of redirect but not a true redirect because using redirect causes some problems with Google.
So I'd like to give *./folder/* instead of *index.php* or *./*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess should look something like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Just replace

```
RewriteBase /
```

With

```
RewriteBase /foldername
```

Comment: my .htaccess doesn't contain any Wordpress rule, that's my htaccess:<br />

    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Well just replace "RewriteBase /" with "RewriteBase /foldername"

Comment: Well i see that you have some rewrite rules to redirect from www to non www. You can use the complete code from my answer and if the folder part works then you can add www to non www rewrite to it.

Comment: it seems to be ignoring them and gives me error 404

Comment: it may sound stupid, but are you replacing the text "/foldername" with your folder name?

Comment: Yes, I've done this changes, at the end I've solved with a simply changes, I've edited index.php and I've wrote:
`<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./folder/wp-blog-header.php');
?>` in this way i've done a sort of first page into the root index

Answer (score 0):

use this redirect

Redirect 301 /index.php /sub/index.php

Comment: i've edit my question, I've expressed it badly- by the way thanks for the Answer